# JavascriptCore isn't calling function with arguments properly

Tags: ios, javascriptcore

I've made an iOS application to install & run javascript scripts and to do so, I'm using JavascriptCore. Some of my scripts are periodic, which means they are started every X seconds for example.

Pseudo-code example:

```
every('X seconds', function(event) {
   save(event.timestamp);
});
```

So far, everything was fine until I realized that after few minutes (~3min) the function I call starts ignoring my argument. I get "undefined" inside my `save` method ! **It's working for some time and then**...

Objective-c code:

```
[_executionContext evaluateScript:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var myFunc = %@", _script]];
[_executionContext[@"myFunc"] callWithArguments:@[event.data]];
```

Explanation

1. I evaluate the `function(event) { ... }` (`script`) string and save it inside `myFunc` object.
2. I call this function with my `event.data` which exposes timestamp. Simple !

Note that even when `event.timestamp` returns undefined my `event.data` object isn't nil ! And I've found nothing wrong inside my objective-c code. I think that something is happening inside callWithArguments method or I'm missing something...

Data interface:

```
@protocol DataExports<JSExport>
@property (nonatomic) long timestamp;
@end

@interface APSData : MTLModel<DataExports>
@end
```

I've the same problem on device and emulator.

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution !

Instead of using `evaluationScript` on my function everytime my event occur I save it once inside a map and I use it to call my function after. So basically:

```
[_executionContext evaluateScript:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var %@ = %@", _functionHash, _script]];
_functionMap[_functionHash] = [_executionContext evaluateScript:_functionHash];
```

And when needed, I call:

```
[_functionMap[_functionHash] callWithArguments:@[event.data]];
```

To me there is no difference with what I did before but it seems to work better...

Edit: Well... It doesn't really work. Now it fails after 10 minutes..